# How to access external URL which requires OAuth2 via Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Currently, the mechanism that we use for authenticating against a server which requires OAuth2 is to write a Java program which contains a main() method, which runs an HttpClient to generate an OAuth2 access token by using this call:

```
https://api.externalsite.com/v1/oauth/token?clientId=iLHuXeULFBdW4B1dmRY0MhFILRQnlfeK&clientSecret=RG3JanXEq2R1GhRvIQ2d2AKRx0SORvb3&grant_type=client_credentials
```

This returns the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOi786I1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6bnVsbCwiZGV2aWNlSWQiOm51bGwsImNsaWVudElkIjoiaUxIdVhlVUxGQmRXNEIxZG1SWTBNaFJPTVJRbmxmZUsiLCJhZElkIjpudWxsLCJleHAiOjE1MjU0MjY4LMYsImlhdCI6MTUyNTQyMzE0Nn0.Zz_uhXqOF2ykC24mNBWHnQ_Vmx-jfQs3X4qcmmN0-Sk",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": null,
    "scope": null
}
```

After obtaining the access token, we are able to run queries using JSON against the authorized website / service.

---

Question(s):

1. Inside a Spring Boot Microservice (2.0.1.RELEASE), how can one use Spring Security or just an HttpClient to use clientId, clientSecret and grant_type to automatically provide a global access token inside each REST call (which might be an HTTP Post) from the REST controller layer?
2. Can someone show a code sample of how to use Spring Security or a different library to just send the clientId, clientSecret, and grant_type to obtain an OAuth2 access token?
3. What to do (using the library from question # 2) if the OAuth2 token expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, just used RestTemplate:

```
String accessToken = OAuth2Client.generateAccessToken();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(request,headers);
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
```

Very easy!

Answer (score 0):

1) You dont need spring security .Just use 'io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts'.
You can use any number of parameters to generate the JWT token .
You can use a component inside your Spring boot application to generate the JWT token .

Then create a Token service that will use this bean and perform :generate access token , validate access token and refresh the token .

2)
Sample :
@Component
public String createJwtToken(User user, TokenType type, ClientKey clientKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

```
   String userName = user.getUsername();

   Date currentTime = new Date();

   String token = Jwts.builder()
     .setSubject(userName)
     .claim(Constants.NAME_KEY, Constants.NAME_VALUE)
     .claim(Constants.USER_TOKEN_KEY, clientKey.getKey())
     .claim(Constants.SCOPE_KEY, Constants.SCOPE_VALUE)
     .claim(Constants.TOKEN_TYPE, type.name())
     .setIssuer(tokenIssuer)
     .setHeaderParam(Constants.TOKEN_TYP, Constants.TOKEN_JWT)
     .setHeaderParam(Constants.TOKEN_TYPE, type.name())
     .setIssuedAt(currentTime)
     .setExpiration(timeout(type))
     .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, key)
     .compact();
   return encrypt(token);
```

}

3) Whenever you generate the token for the first time you generate 2 tokens : accessToken and Refresh Token .
AccessToken is short lived and expires soon . - say 5 mins .
The refresh token has a onger expiry duration : eg: 20 mins .

Purpose of refresh token is that you can use the refresh token to generate the new access token .
So when ur access token expires, just make a call to the refresh token method by passing ur refresh token . This method should return the user from redis with the new access token .

Regards,

R Rai

Comment: Thanks Rai - Your code sample gave me a lot of issues in Eclipse. I don't have a user and I don't know where the package import is for Constants comes from. I just need to find a Java library which can take a client_id, client_secret, and grant_type = client_credentials.  I don't l know what to put for TokenType, ClientKey, and tokenIssuer?

Comment: You are generating the token on behalf of some entity . It could be a User, it could be an Organization or it could be a System Identifier . I just gave you an example of a user .

Comment: Constants, just create a class  to store static values:
public class Constants {public static final String TOKEN_TYP = "typ";
  public static final String TOKEN_JWT = "JWT";
  public static final String TOKEN_TYPE = "TOKEN_TYPE";
  public static final String USER_TOKEN_KEY = "USER_KEY";
public static final TimeUnit TOKEN_TIMEUNIT = TimeUnit.MINUTES;
  public static final String NAME_KEY = "name";
  public static final String NAME_VALUE = "COMPAN";
}
TokenType, ClientKey, and tokenIssuer are just parameters used to generate ur token . You can replace these with any paraeters you need .

Answer (score 0):

Found an OAuth2Client which open sourced and offered by IBM:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-oauthjavapt1/index.html#download